# Redirecting URL with elseif $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Tags: php, redirect, header, http-redirect

I have a main page that users go to that shows output from a MySQL query depending on the variable passed to it.  So;

```
http://website/mypage.php?page=0
```

However, I would like to set up redirection so that if someone just goes to

```
http://website/mypage.php
```

that it will go to `http://website/mypage.php?page=0`.  I thought of using the following code, which verifies the current page as well as verifies that a user's session is established;

```
elseif ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/mypage.php' && isset($_SESSION['valid_user']))
{
header('Refresh: 0; URL=/mypage.php?page=0');
}
```

But, this looks to be too general.  Is there a way to check for exactly '/mypage.php' or maybe '/mypage.php?page=' ?  I thought of using strlen to check for only the 11 characters in /mypage.php, but I'm not sure that this is the most efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `mypage.php` you can check something like this

```
if(!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    header('location: /mypage.php?page=0');
    exit;
}
```

But, I think, instead of redirecting to same page with a get variable, why don't just show the page you want to show by default, when there is no `page` variable is set.

Comment: Wow, I should have thought of that.  Thank you so much, that's a great solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can check to see if the variable page has a value and if its empty you can do the redirect

```
if($_GET['page'] == ''){
  header('Location: /mypage.php?page=0');
  exit;
}
```

or

```
if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
  header('Location: /mypage.php?page=0');
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this way:

```
header('Location: /mypage.php?page=0');
exit;
```

Otherwise check the $_SERVER variables for more strict match. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

I think probably you need `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
if(!isset($_GET['page']) || empty($_GET['page'])) {
    Header('Location: http://website/mypage.php?page=0')
    exit();
}
```

or

```
if(!isset($_GET['page']))
    $_GET['page'] = 0;
```

I'm not sure about the second solution, you shouldn't attribute value to $_GET[] variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( !isset($_REQUEST['page']) ) {
    header('Location: /mypage.php?page=0');
    exit(0);
} else {
    if( $_REQUEST['page']=="" ) {
        header('Location: /mypage.php?page=0');
        exit(0);
    }
}
```